# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 with Qt and OpenCV

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

I am working on a desktop application with the Qt and OpenCV on my mac. I have installed both qmake on version 5.3.2(currently used) and 4.6.8 , OpenCV 2.4.9 , I use the GCC compiler, my Qt version is 5.3.2, Qt creator version is 3.2.2.

Previously I have a Qt project previously run on a Ubuntu, now it migrates to the mac, the only change is just on the .pro, in which the INCLUDEPATH and LIB path must change to the include and lib path of OpenCV in the mac.

Here is my configuration.

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_objdetect \
-lopencv_ml \
-lopencv_features2d
```

/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include and /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib are the exact location for the opencv. There should be no reason to have this error, since the opencv libraries are all there and should be linked in the right format.

right now I could not figure out how and why

Comment: sorry, my QT is 5.3.2, and QT creator version 3.2.2

Comment: Are all the libraries you are linking to 64bit?

Comment: i used the brew install opencv to install it, probably 64 bit, how do I check